# How to set heap size for Quarkus app using Jib container image?

Tags: quarkus, jib

I'm Quarkus 1.11.0 and trying to set the heap size of my app using...

`quarkus.jib.jvm-arguments=-Xms1024m -Xmx1024m -agentpath:/app/resources/libyjpagent.so=listen=all` also tried with capital M and I get `Invalid initial heap size` and the app exits.

I also tried through the env `JAVA_OPTS` and `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS` and these don't seem to do anything, the app just runs but the heap size is not set.

Comment: Is `quarkus.jib.jvm-arguments` not working?

Comment: No. Thats exactly what I'm saying. Unless the -agentpath with multiple = signs in it screwing up the parsing internally. I'll test without it.

Comment: did you manage to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `quarkus.jib.jvm-additional-arguments` if you just want to add arguments.

Comment: See, my question I'm using quarkus.jib.jvm-arguments on 1.11.0 is the quarkus.jib.jvm-additional-arguments for newer versions.

Comment: `1.11` is pretty old at this point so you are advised to move up

Answer (score 0):

In addition to geoand's answer, use a comma-separated list, like so:

```
quarkus.jib.jvm-additional-arguments=-XX:MaxRAMPercentage=75.0,-XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions,-XX:+UseG1GC,-XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio=15,-XX:MinHeapFreeRatio=5
```